# CSS animation not working on span with animate.css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, animate.css

I have a `<button>` and a `<span>` inside a tab. I want to add animate.css classes to span when hover over button. I'm using angular to include them.

It doesn't work in chrome (it does work in ie):

```
<div>
    <button ng-mouseover="one()" ng-mouseleave="two()">Hover over me</button>
    <span ng-class="{animated : zero, bounce : zero}">Animate me</span>
</div>

<script>
    function controlTotal($scope) {

        $scope.zero = false;

        $scope.one = function () {
            $scope.zero = true;
        };

        $scope.three = function () {
            $scope.zero = false;
        };

    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block;` with the span:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;" 
    ng-class="{animated : zero, bounce : zero}">Animate me</span>
```

[Animate.css GitHub](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/515):

> Historically, **span elements can't be animated with CSS. In order to animate them, you'll need to give them a display property**. Obviously display: block; will give you undesirable effects, so assigning display: inline-block would be a better choice, and solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. I didn't know that about spans. Always happy to learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what You need to do:

```
<button ng-mouseover="one()" ng-mouseleave="two()">Hover over me</button>
<span style="display:inline-block" ng-class="{animated:zero,bounce :zero}">Animate me</span>
```